# You don't have any device tokens registered yet - Urban Airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, push-notification

I use Urban Airship for push notifications. Below is status.

```
2013-03-21 14:39:16.231 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAPush applicationDidBecomeActive] [Line 555] Checking registration status after foreground notification
2013-03-21 14:39:16.232 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAPush applicationDidBecomeActive] [Line 561] Checking registration on app foreground disabled on app initialization
2013-03-21 14:39:16.399 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAUser listenForDeviceTokenReg] [Line 931] ListenForDeviceTokenReg
2013-03-21 14:39:17.530 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAUser retrieveRequestSucceeded:] [Line 873] User retrieved: 200:{
  "user_id" : "z3hUpYOpRKeLOAfKyjIvRQ",
  "user_url" : "https://device-api.urbanairship.com/api/user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "tags" : [ ],
  "device_tokens" : [ ],
  "device_pins" : [ ],
  "apids" : [ ],
  "has_active_subscription" : false,
  "subscriptions" : [ ],
  "ua_device_ids" : [ "xx-DFxxAB-xx-xxx-xxx" ],
  "badge" : 0,
  "server_time" : "2013-03-21 11:39:18"
}
2013-03-21 14:39:17.550 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAUser updateDefaultDeviceToken] [Line 978] Updating device token.
2013-03-21 14:39:17.552 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAUser updateDefaultDeviceToken] [Line 981] Skipping device token update: no token, already up to date, or user is being updated.
2013-03-21 14:39:31.123 SAMA[18048:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 275] Retrieved device id info from keychain.
2013-03-21 14:39:31.124 SAMA[18048:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 279] Device ID result is not nil.
2013-03-21 14:39:31.125 SAMA[18048:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 288] Loaded Device ID: xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-03-21 14:39:31.126 SAMA[18048:907] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 289] Loaded Model Name: iPhone4,1
2013-03-21 14:39:32.399 SAMA[18048:907] [D] -[UAAnalytics requestDidSucceed:response:responseData:] [Line 461] Analytics data sent successfully. Status: 200
```

Still in my account, I see **`You don't have any device tokens registered yet.`**

Even when I run app, it didn't ask for push notification confirmation also.

I did everything as per [their documentation](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+iOS%3a+Push). But still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Perfect solution for Urban Airship is

1. Create App ID
2. Enable APNS
3. Then create Provision File

(Note : Delete all profiles that you have on computer and from Organizer window too). Don't keep the provisioning profile for that project in xcode. delete earlier and do above steps again. Problem will be solved.